# Как сдвинуть edittext вниз android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня разметка для поля:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/field_login"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:textColor="#DCDCDC"
            android:textColorHint="#DCDCDC" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

и вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот собственно вопрос - как мне сдвинуть немного вниз линию edittext чтобы курсор не налезал на нее и иконка как-будто висела над ней(линией).

Comment: а покажите, пожалуйста, как выглядит `EditText` с курсором

Comment: @iFr0z, обновил вопрос

Comment: Что-то прям очень странно. А смущают `margin`'ы в `TextInputLayout`. Они использовались для того, чтобы вместить картинку?

Comment: не в тему, но может буть: у вас часть размеров в `sp`, часть в `dp`... документация советует использовать `sp` только для текстов. Ну и вообще, по идее - дело в паддинге, попробуйте увеличить

Comment: @Jarvis_J, в каком именно паддинге?

Comment: @iFr0z, margin'ы использовались для задания размеров поля и все, картинка никак не меняется

Comment: это для картинки используется, но я пробовал ничего не изменилось почти, только курсор немного двинулся и все

Comment: `android:padding="5dp"` - попробуйте этот увеличить

Comment: у меня есть еще одно поле с паролем, и там есть глаз для показа пароля, вот там все красиво, но все красиво из-за глаза, он двигает поле

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас проблема в `android:padding="5sp"`

Во-первых отступы в `sp` в андройде не задаются.

Во-вторых удалите его - и не будет налазить